# graphics.h programs not running in Dosbox Windows 7 environment

Tags: c, dosbox, turbo-c, bgi

I have installed Dosbox to run Turbo C in it. But my graphics.h programs are not executing in it. I am getting Linker Error which says"Undefined sumbol initgraph in module..." and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is quite simple to solve.

Open your Turboc IDE

Click on options
click on linker
click on libraries
mark the graphics option(a cross mark usually)
now run.

Answer (score 1):

You are not linking the required graphics library. It has been quite a while since I last used Turbo C, but if I remember correctly, you can simply configure the toolchain to link the graphics lib in the linker options which are easily accessible from the Turbo C "IDE".

Answer (score 1):

If You are getting Error in Windows XP that `Undefined symbol initgraph in module`
then follow the Steps :

1. Go to Console
2. Go to Options
3. Go to Linker
4. Go to Libraries
5. Make "X" Mark on Graphics Library